# consuming soap web services in a java spring app

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

Ok, so there is a third party SOAP web services I need to use in my java Spring app.

I have the address and the WSDL. The service works fine in SoapUI.

To have it working in my spring java client, I got my inspiration from this spring tutorial 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/
This tutorial works fine with this weather service.

However, If i use that tutorial with my wsdl, generating the classes, then adding a XXXClient and XXXConfiguration class, it compiles fine but fails when the soap service is actually called.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: The message with Action 'https://XXX/Services/FormsSignIn' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
```

In the weatherClient class from the tutorial, the code is as follow.

```
public GetCityForecastByZIPResponse getCityForecastByZip(String zipCode) {
    GetCityForecastByZIP request = new GetCityForecastByZIP();
    request.setZIP(zipCode);
    log.info("Requesting forecast for " + zipCode);
    GetCityForecastByZIPResponse response = (GetCityForecastByZIPResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(
                    "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx",
                    request,
                    new SoapActionCallback("http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityForecastByZIP"));
    return response;
}
```

In my case, i don't know anything about that ".asmx" extension. In SoapUI, i can see the endpoint ends with ".svc" so i used it at the same location (maybe to do with WCF).

```
public String getSessionToken() {
    FormsSignIn request  = new FormsSignIn();
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    request.setUserName(factory.createFormsSignInUserName(APPUSER_USERNAME));
    request.setPassword(factory.createFormsSignInPassword(APPUSER_PASSWORD));
    request.setForceSignIn(true);

    FormsSignInResponse response = (FormsSignInResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(
                    "https://XXX/Services/svcAppUser.svc",
                    request,
                    new SoapActionCallback( "https://XXXX/Services/FormsSignIn" ));
    String sessionID = response.getFormsSignInResult().getValue();
    System.out.println("sessionID="+sessionID);

    return sessionID;
}
```

Anyway, it just doesn't seem to work in my spring app. Any idea?

Comment: The way the request object is being constructed is incorrect, construct it through the ObjectFactory instance.

Comment: if i do FormsSignIn request  = factory.createFormsSignIn(); it makes no difference :-(

Comment: The SOAPFault is mainly due to the invalid format of your request..print your request in XML and try hit the Service using SOAP UI. By this way you can trace the issue.